# Find the limit of $\dfrac{\phi(n)}{n}$ where $\phi$ is a permutation of $\Bbb N$

Tags: limits, natural-numbers

Find the limit of $\dfrac{\phi(n)}{n}$ where $\phi$ is a permutation of $\Bbb N$.
A permutation of $\Bbb N$  is a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$, based on pure intuition it seems like the limit should be $1$ however I can't come up with a proof.
An already established result is that  $(\phi(n))_n$ diverges to infinity.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the limit exists? Or do you have a particular permutation in mind?

Comment: Can't really imagine such permutation to not be a linear function of $n$, it's still just a hunch

Comment: What about $\phi(n) = n^2$ for even $n$, and assigning the “remaining values” to $\phi(n)$ for odd $n$? – $1, 4, 2, 16, 3, 36, 5, 64, \ldots$

Comment: It's easy to show that a limit not necessarily exists.

Comment: Oh I missed having the case where the permutation is defined by partition, seems like an obvious one to conisder. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one without limit: Partition the natural numbers at the powers of 2. Let the permutation reverse each partition. The fraction $\frac{\phi(n)}n$ will bounce between $2$ and $\frac12$ infinitely many times.

If you pick partitions that grow in size faster than exponential (say you partition at each factorial), then the fraction goes arbitrarily close to $0$ and arbitrarily large as $n$ grows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wonder if the only case where it converges is the identity then

Comment: @Ouchna Not at all. Let the partitions have constant size (e.g. split at each even number) (or just bounded size), and you'll see many permutations where the limit exists. Or let the permutation only touch a finite number of numbers.